# Check if multiple variables are empty and replace only those who are empty

Tags: python, openpyxl

Hi everyone i need some help, possibly is an easy thing, but as im new in programming and python im not getting there, it would be awsome if someone could help me..

So i have multiple variables that i get from openpyxl i need to replace individualy if they are None, i tried the way bellow, but if one variable is None it will replace all of them, i need to replace only those who are None :

```
    DU = sheet['B18'].value
    bl_n = sheet['G17'].value #on excel is None
    incoterm = sheet['B23'].value #on excel is None
    transporter = sheet['G23'].value

if None in (bl_n,incoterm,DU, transporter):
    bl_n="none"
    incoterm="none"
    DU ="none"
    transporter="none"
else:
    DU = sheet['B18'].value
    bl_n = sheet['G17'].value
    incoterm = sheet['B23'].value
    transporter = sheet['G23'].value`
```

Output:

```
    DU - none
    bl_n - none
    incoterm - none
    transporter - none
```

What i need:

```
    DU - 5555555555555555
    bl_n - none
    incoterm - none
    transporter - x124455714
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: You need to check each individually, and if you find one, then set it to none rather than all at the same time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simply use an `or` during initial variable assignment.

```py
DU = sheet['B18'].value or "none"
bl_n = sheet['G17'].value or "none" #on excel is None
incoterm = sheet['B23'].value or "none" #on excel is None
transporter = sheet['G23'].value or "none"
```

To further clarify, `or` is a `boolean` operator. It converts the expression before and after to a `boolean`. If the first expression evaluates to `True` i.e. it is not `None`, it returns the first value, otherwise the second value is returned, which in this case is always `True`.

Edit: A potential pitfall for some cases, as I've just realized. Since the `or` checks for the truth value, all of `0`, `False` and `None` will result in the second expression being returned.

Comment: Thanks, that will make things even easier for me, i really apreciate the help, and sorry for my poor knowledge on this.

Comment: We're all here to learn. :)

Answer (score 1):

Check them individually:

```py
bl_n = "none" if bl_n is None else bl_n
incoterm = "none" if incoterm is None else incoterm
DU = "none" if DU is None else DU
transporter = "none" if transporter is None else transporter
```

Comment: Thanks, that works, i was trying to make it a bit more simple since i have like 40 variables like that, i will use the or on the variable assignment (easier for me on this case) but  i really apreciate the help, and sorry for my poor knowledge on this.

Answer (score 0):

I would use `map` in the following way

```
DU,bl_n,incoterm,transporter = map(lambda x: "none" if x is None else x, [DU,bl_n,incoterm,transporter])
```